# designated initializer missing a super call to a designated initializer of the super class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-2.0

I'm getting 2 warnings in the pods like 1. designated initializer missing a super call to a designated initializer of the super class. 2. Designated initializer should only invoke a designated intializer on super.

`- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)ignoredFrame {
    return [self init];
}`

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, this will remove warnings

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)ignoreframe {
    self = [super initWithFrame:ignoreframe];
    if (self) {
        // load view frame XIB
    }
    return self;
}
```

To know more in details, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053037/7754752)